# How do I automatically center a fixed element?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm currently attempting to keep my header menu fixed at the top of the screen, even when scrolling.  The issue is that whenever I set the position to fixed, it loses it's centering, and margin has no effect on it.  I want to be able to center the element while still enabling it to automatically center itself when the page is resized or viewed by a smaller resolution.

The HTML and CSS in question:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1{
    font: bold 20px Tahoma
}
h2{
    font: bold 20px Tahoma
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article {
    display: block;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(143, 143, 143);
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#big_wrapper{
    margin: 0 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 100%;

}
#top_header{
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    height: 120px;
    background: rgb(45,45,45);
    /*border-bottom: 15px solid rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.4);*/
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: rgb(30, 30, 30) 10px 10px 10px;*/
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
#centering_example{
    color: #a00d01;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) -3px 3px 0;
}
#new_div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#main_section{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 140px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #3c3c3c;
    box-shadow: rgb(30, 30, 30) 10px 10px 10px;
}
#the_footer{
    position: relative;
    top: 140px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background: #3c3c3c;
    box-shadow: rgb(30, 30, 30) 10px 10px 10px;
}
#SELECTED{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background: rgba(36,34,31, 0.6);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 0 0;;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.media_button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    background: rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.8);
    padding: 3px 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 3px 3px 0;
    color: #787878;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.media_button:hover{
    background: rgba(59,59,59, 0.6);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 2px 2px 0;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}
.media_button:active {
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background: rgba(36, 34, 31, 0.6);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 0 0;
}
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    background: rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.8);
    padding: 9px 18px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 3px 3px 0;
    color: #787878;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover{
    background: rgba(59,59,59, 0.6);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 2px 2px 0;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}
.button:active{
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background: rgba(36,34,31, 0.6);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="big_wrapper">
    <header id="top_header">
        <p id="centering_example">centering help</p>
        <a id="SELECTED" class="button" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="button">Games</a>
        <a class="button">About us</a>
        <a class="button">Blog</a>

    </header>

    <div id="new_div">

        <section id="main_section">
            <article>
                <p>This is text for the index page of the website.</p>
                <br>
            </article>

        </section>

    </div>

    <footer id="the_footer">
        <h6>Footer text</h6>
        <a class="media_button" href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
        <a class="media_button" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
        <a class="media_button" href="http://steamcommunity.com">Steam Group</a>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving it a `left:50%;` and a margin-left which is minus half the width.

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -200px;
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3vh99vg/1/

A better way (suggested by zgood in a comment below), which does not use hardcoded margins is to translate the element on the x-axis by 50%;

```
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3vh99vg/2/

Comment: It might be better to use `transformX(-50%)` instead of having a hard-code negative margin.

Comment: @zgood Perhaps a stupid question, but how might I implement that?

Comment: @HaukurHaf here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3vh99vg/2/). The property is `transform:translateX(-50%);` not `transformX(-50%)`

Comment: @CloudTwoNJ see my comment above

Comment: Wow, I thought I just tried that myself.  Must have had a typo in there somewhere.  This works fine :-)

Comment: @zgood Any idea why the sides of the buttons are getting slightly offset when the suggested property is set?

Comment: @CloudTwoNJ I'm not sure I understand. The buttons seem to stay in the same place when `margin-left:-200px` is used or when nothing is used

Comment: @zgood Sorry about that, it was actually an issue with something else I did on my end that messed up the right border of a few of my buttons.  Don't mind the previous comment, as it no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
#top_header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: YOUR WIDTH;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gLz8zur/

Comment: a fixed width is probably a bad idea

Comment: I agree, but thats what his design is asking for.  He could wrap it in a  container, but thats adding html, which is outside of his original question.

Comment: How is adding html outside of the original question? He doesn't say anything about a pure CSS solution... the question is tagged with both html and css

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to be a dick. You're just making assumptions (only css can change and must be 100% backwards compatible) and thus giving sub par answers. This is a site about helping people not spreading bad advice

Comment: Agree... and I definitely was not spreading bad advice or making assumptions.  Technically I was spreading fully supported advice.  The only assumption I made was that the above code was so crappy that I didn't think a modern, css3 approach was the best answer.  I could of easily called you out for giving incorrect markup above.... `transformX(-50%)`....  but didn't.

Comment: fyi: `display: flex;` is css3, which is used throughout his example.

Comment: So are `<br>` tags for spacing, anchor tags without `href`, and a heavy use of IDs on almost every element.  So ya... crappy code.  And thank you for all the css 'pointers'... its been a pleasure.

Comment: @SeanStopnik I hadn't planned on commenting just to add to this near-pointless flaming, but I feel I should defend myself for the above statement.  The reason for all mentioned above are because this is something I edited from my main project file, and not the project itself.  The break tags were for testing the fixed position, the lack of href tags was due to my removing the file references, and the amount of ID's was due to me using a number of different styles, not all of which are present here.  This is a place to help others with their coding, not start a flame war.

Comment: @CloudTwoNJ definitely not starting any wars... And known of it was directed towards you. The commenter above just came at me from the start without really considering all possible reasons first. Using a transform is a straight forward answer, but not a fully supported one. I was aiming towards the fully supported answer. But either way... You got your answer. Good luck with things.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap you `header` content in a div and then give your `header` a style of `display:flex` along with `position:fixed`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hafbuwo/).

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="top_header">
        <p id="centering_example">centering help</p>
        <a id="SELECTED" class="button" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="button">Games</a>
        <a class="button">About us</a>
        <a class="button">Blog</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```