# When setting a fixed navbar and footer, my margins go away?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where I have a Navbar and a Footer that I am making fixed. Before fixed, they had margins (white space on both right and left) which is what I wanted.

Now when I make it fixed, all of a sudden the margins are being overridden or ignored.

I am unsure how to get the margins to come back so it makes sense with my page.

These are the relevant styling for the footer and nav that I am using.

```
.nav-wrapper {
  padding-left: 30px;

}

nav .signin-container, .profile, .container, .sign-up {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -75px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

footer .row, .push {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 75px;
}
footer{
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: margins are ignored on absolute or fixed positioned element. Can you provide a fiddle and explain what do you want to achieve with your layout?

Comment: Could you maybe do a jsfiddle to point out your problem better

Comment: I am guessing the "margins" are coming from a parent element, because you do not have margin left or right on either fixed element. So when you apply the position:fixed, it ignores the parent margins. Also, you have "left:0" and "right:0" which is making it align at the very edge of the page.

Comment: How wide to you want the header/footer to be?

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626955/how-do-i-automatically-center-a-fixed-element

Answer (score 0):

To make the elements match the margin, you would need to change the values of the `left` and `right` attributes.

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
    left:15px;
    right:15px;
}

footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:15px;
    right:15px;
}
```

Or, perhaps, you want to keep those containing elements to the edge and you just want the content to match margin spacing. Then maybe you would like to simply add inner-padding:

```
nav {
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
}

footer {
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Is there a way to keep the margins the same, or more clearly lined up, when the window is resized?

Comment: You will need to clarify more with what you want to achieve. At this point, probably a link, or screenshots will help us understand the situation a bit more.

Comment: For example :

https://pearlern.herokuapp.com/

When I resize the page, the margins stay the same. This version is before I did the fixed position. Now with the fixed position, and adjusting based off 'left' and 'right' when I resize the window the navbar and footer do not stay adjust appropriately but rather adjust based on the 'left' right' coming out as odd.

Comment: When I do 'position:relative' of course it re-adjusts when the window size is changed but it is no longer fixed.